# No existing service instances found in IBM Watson Studio

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-studio

When I am adding cloud storage in IBM Watson Studio it shows

`No existing service instances found`

So, I try to add lite cloud storage which is free but it gets added with default location global. How do I make it to some other country?

Answer (score 2):

IBM Cloud Object Storage is a Global service so the default location of global is to be expected. More information can be found regarding provisioning COS at  https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/basics?topic=cloud-object-storage-provision#provision-instance

Buckets however can be created in a single region if necessary. More details on Buckets can be found at: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-getting-started#gs-create-buckets

When you create your Watson Studio project, you will see that the bucket will be created in the region where your Watson Studio is located.